# Kidney stone treatment - Conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Question:

> The table below shows the success rates and numbers of treatments for treatments involving both small and large kidney stones, where Treatment A includes open surgical procedures and Treatment B includes closed surgical procedures. The numbers in parentheses indicate the number of success cases over the total size of the group.
>
> $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
> \text{Stone size\Treatment} & \text{Treatment A}& \text{Treatment B} \\ \hline
> \text{Small stones} & \text{Group  1}& \text{Group 2} \\ 
> & \text{93%}(\frac{81}{87}) & \text{87%}{(\frac{234}{270})}\\ \hline
> \text{Large stones}  & \text{Group 3}& \text{Group 4}\\
> & \text{73%}(\frac{192}{263)} & \text{69%}{(\frac{55}{80})}\\ \hline
> \text{Both} & 78\%(\frac{273}{350}) &\text{83%}(\frac{289}{350})\\ \hline
> \end{array}$$

Suppose a patient is randomly selected. Let  $S$ := Patient has small stones, $C$ := The treatment was successful, and $A$ := The patient was given Treatment A. Using the following result (*) and conditioning on $S$, verify the values for $\Pr \left( {C \mid A} \right)$ and $\Pr \left( {C \mid {A^c}} \right)$.

> (*) Let $\left\{ {{B_1},{B_2}, \ldots } \right\}$ be events that are pairwise mutually exclusive and exhaustive, and $A$, $C$ be arbitrary events. Then: $$\Pr \left( {A \mid C} \right) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\Pr \left( {A \mid {B_n} \cap C} \right)\Pr \left( {{B_n} \mid C} \right)} $$

So my confusion is:

In the case of finding $\Pr \left( {C \mid A} \right)$, is the following the right use of the result (*) with ''conditioning on $S$''? 
$$\begin{gathered}
  \Pr \left( {C \mid A} \right) &  = \Pr \left( {C \mid \left( {S \cap A} \right)} \right) \cdot \Pr \left( {S \mid A} \right) + \Pr \left( {C \mid \left( {{S^c} \cap A} \right)} \right) \cdot \Pr \left( {{S^c} \mid A} \right) \hfill \\
   &  = \frac{{\Pr \left( {C \cap S \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( {S \cap A} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{\Pr \left( {S \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( A \right)}} + \frac{{\Pr \left( {C \cap {S^c} \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( {{S^c} \cap A} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{\Pr \left( {{S^c} \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( A \right)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, as you can see by simplifying the last expression.

$$\frac{{\Pr \left( {C \cap S \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( {S \cap A} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{\Pr \left( {S \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( A \right)}} + \frac{{\Pr \left( {C \cap {S^c} \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( {{S^c} \cap A} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{\Pr \left( {{S^c} \cap A} \right)}}{{\Pr \left( A \right)}}
\\=\frac{\Pr(C\cap S\cap A)}{\Pr(A)}+\frac{\Pr(C\cap S^c\cap A)}{\Pr(A)}
\\=\frac{\Pr((C\cap S\cap A)\cup(C\cap S^c\cap A))}{\Pr(A)}
\\=\frac{\Pr(C\cap A)}{\Pr(A)}=\Pr(C|A)
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is ${\Pr \left( {C \cap S \cap A} \right)}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{81}}{{87}}$ or is it ${\Pr \left( {C \cap S \cap A} \right)}= \frac{{81}}{{87}}$? And is ${\Pr \left( A \right) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{87}}{{350}} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{{263}}{{350}}}$

Comment: @There are $700$ patients in the trial, and $81$ with small stones successfully treated with treatment A, so I would say $$\Pr \left( {C \cap S \cap A} \right)=\frac{81}{700}$$